# Avoid running the script if a variable is not defined

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a script looks like:

```sh
c=0
for f in */*; do
cp -v "$f" "/myhome/CE$(printf '%0*d' 2 $BATCHNUM)-new-stuctures_extracted/test-$(printf '%0*d' 5 $c)"
c=$((c=c+1))
done
```

However, the user must provide a variable call BATCHNUM and otherwise I need to force this script stop running. It will be better if I could force the script that calls this script to stop too (or even the #1 script that calls #2 script which calls this script).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The quickest way is probably to add these two lines to the start of the script:

```
set -u # or set -o nounset
: "$BATCHNUM"
```

The first line sets the `nounset` option in the shell running the script, which aborts if you try to expand an unset variable; the second expands `$BATCHNUM` in the context of a no-op, to trigger the abort before doing anything else.

If you want a more helpful error message, you could instead write:

```
if [[ -z "$BATCHNUM" ]]; then
    echo "Must provide BATCHNUM in environment" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Or similar.

Comment: `[[ -z "$BATCHNUM" ]]` still triggers the error, at least in dash. I had to use `[[ -z "${BATCHNUM:-}" ]]`

Answer (score 50):

Here you want to check `BATCHNUM` is set and not null.

POSIX shell provide a [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for this job. Just adding this line before using `BATCHNUM`:

```
: "${BATCHNUM:?Variable not set or empty}"
```

or better to set the default value for `BATCHNUM` if user didn't provide one:

```
: "${BATCHNUM:=3}"
```

Comment: I'd just modify the message to repeat the var name, as it won't be displayed otherwise: `: "${BATCHNUM:?Variable BATCHNUM not set or empty}"`, and follow it by another test & exit ( for ex: `if [ -z "${BATCHNUM}" ]; then exit 1 ; fi` ). Or better, just that later test, and display a message before the exit? Just displaying something when a var is unset is rarely useful (unless the script recovers from it later on. )

Comment: You can also omit the error message, and write "${BATCHNUM:?}". This will print a generic error message: `bash: BATCHNUM: parameter null or not set`

Answer (score 6):

The lines

```
if [ -z "$BATCHNUM" ]; then
    exit 2;
fi
```

check for empty `$BATCHNUM`. With `$PPID` you can do whatever harm you want to your parent (`kill $PPID`). For murdering your grandparent, you need to get the process id by other means, like looking at the data in `/proc/$PPID`.

However, if your parent dies, it sends a signal (`SIGHUP`) to you, so you have to trap it before you start killing anybody:

```
trap '' SIGHUP
```

**Update:** If you think you have to kill your parents, you doing it wrong. Just return a meaningfull exitcode. The parent script should check the called script's return code and react accordingly.

Comment: a bit brutal.... :)

Answer (score 6):

```
[ -n "$BATCHNUM" ] || { kill "$PPID"; exit 1; }
#Unless $BATCHNUM is defined and unempty, ask parent process to exit and exit w/ 1
```

This will work on bash and in a POSIX sh. I prefer not to differentiate between empty variables and undefined variables (i.e., I don't like `set -u`, but that's just me).

Answer (score 3):

To test if `BATCHNUM` is defined, and exit if it isn't:

```
if [ -n "${BATCHNUM-a}" ]; then
  echo >&2 "Fatal error: BATCHNUM not set"
  exit 2
fi
```

If you also want to reject the case where `BATCHNUM` is empty, use `${BATCHNUM:+a}` instead of `${BATCHNUM+a}`. For information about the `${VARIABLE+TEXT_IF_NULL}` parameter expansion construct, see e.g. the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Don't kill the parent process. You don't know what the parent process is. If some script that calls this one needs to abort if this script aborts, make it check the exit status of this script. E.g. in script #2:

```
script3 || exit $?
```

or use [`set -e`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) to abort the script if any command returns a failure (nonzero) status.